# MariaDB view add comment to columns

Tags: mariadb

It's a view not a table

```
SELECT COALESCE(title, 'sum')as title,
       SUM( HOUR(record_datetime) = 8 ) AS t08,
       SUM( HOUR(record_datetime) = 9 ) AS t09,
       COUNT(*) as total
FROM click_log
GROUP BY title WITH ROLLUP
```

Is it possible to add comments to every column?

`` COMMENT 'Hour8`t`n' ``

I didn't find instruction in manual. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-view/

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard supports two types of Tables: the physically existent (Base table) and the derived table (View).

While a base table has a physical schema, a view is computed by a select statement. So the only possibility would be to add comments to the select statement, but this doesn't work since comments will be optimized away.

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT "foo" /* value foo */;

SELECT view_definition from information_schema.views where table_name="v1";
+-----------------------+
| view_definition       |
+-----------------------+
| select 'foo' AS `foo` |
+-----------------------+
```